# Erro de previsao usando o pacote forecast no R

Tags: machine-learning, regressão, series-temporais, forecast

Estou tentando criar uma previsão de series temporais nos dados de teste, porém quando tento fazer a previsão dá um erro que não consigo entender e nem achei nada parecido na internet que pudesse me ajudar

o codigo é esse
dados do modelo de regressão:
Coefficients:
Week                   A                      B                      C
(Intercept)  1577059200.0000016689       13307.1406976744         421.9365116279       11764.1041860465
trend            604799.9999999421         -49.6406976744           3.3934883721         132.4958139535
season2              -0.0000024300       -1623.2493023256         -60.2734883721         470.3541860465
season3              -0.0000023707        -604.0286046512        -179.6569767442        2591.2983720930
season4              -0.0000023117       -1379.5779069767         -71.5704651163        6243.1025581395
season5              -0.0000022545         105.0627906977         284.0460465116        5645.9267441860
season6              -0.0000021965         803.5434883721         281.5725581395        6478.3109302326
season7              -0.0000021393        1737.4641860465         131.2590697674        3960.7951162791
season8              -0.0000020813          30.2548837209          -5.4344186047        3176.7893023256
season9              -0.0000020232         315.1155813953          73.0420930233         507.0134883721
season10             -0.0000019661        -781.9337209302        -112.1913953488        3645.3976744186
season11             -0.0000019080       -1231.4530232558          -0.8148837209        7179.2918604651
season12             -0.0000018508       -3027.0323255814         -38.7483720930        5806.9260465116
season13             -0.0000017928       -1588.9116279070         -13.0818604651        3730.9402325581
season14             -0.0000017347        1877.0090697674          42.1546511628        4102.3644186046
season15             -0.0000016766        -274.2702325581         209.0811627907        4020.0586046512
season16             -0.0000016190       -1090.6695348837         524.4476744186        4888.0827906977
season17             -0.0000015614         315.9711627907         318.2541860465        6092.6869767442
season18             -0.0000015035       -1140.1881395349         130.1006976744        3948.4811627907
season19             -0.0000014456       -1184.5874418605         -52.6427906977        4073.0553488372
season20             -0.0000013878        -369.5467441860         -32.0062790698        9121.6195348837
season21             -0.0000013298         250.0139534884         -63.1997674419        6973.1537209302
season22             -0.0000012720           5.4646511628          42.7867441860        3997.8279069767
season23             -0.0000012141          25.2053488372          91.1332558140        5013.4020930233
season24             -0.0000011563        -406.6939534884           6.8397674419        3984.1962790698
season25             -0.0000010982       -3148.6532558140         162.1362790698        3399.8304651163
season26             -0.0000010406       -3424.1425581395         219.2927906977        2694.0746511628
season27             -0.0000009826        -113.8518604651         262.5693023256        1899.1488372093
season28             -0.0000009254        2670.3188372093         223.5458139535        3381.9730232558
season29             -0.0000008673        3248.1395348837         239.8223255814        3981.8772093023
season30             -0.0000008093        3307.4502325581         124.7188372093        4761.7113953488
season31             -0.0000007521         346.1609302326         123.1253488372        4663.9155813953
season32             -0.0000006941        -349.7383720930          17.2918604651        2963.4197674419
season33             -0.0000006360        -412.4876744186         -36.9816279070        2769.7739534884
season34             -0.0000005789         975.1930232558         134.8448837209        3458.8481395349
season35             -0.0000005217          66.4437209302         158.1513953488        1863.2823255814
season36             -0.0000004627        -421.4255813953         279.3679069767        1236.9665116279
season37             -0.0000004037         666.7451162791         467.8744186047        3097.1906976744
season38             -0.0000003466         528.0558139535         573.3609302326        6293.6748837209
season39             -0.0000002894       -2108.7134883721         113.5574418605        3380.1890697674
season40             -0.0000002304         532.4272093023         -74.7060465116        1339.8432558140
season41             -0.0000001751         431.9679069767         -82.3495348837         871.3774418605
season42             -0.0000001161         727.4286046512          13.9569767442        2422.8916279070
season43             -0.0000000590        1000.1093023256          57.6234883721        2077.4158139535
season44                        NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
Receita
(Intercept)      506702.1467441845
trend               557.6532558140
season2           96953.5367441874
season3           89019.2534883733
season4           47162.2302325593
season5           91814.4669767455
season6            6789.0937209311
season7           30525.2204651173
season8          -38702.4727906966
season9           54888.2739534896
season10          32269.0506976755
season11          31287.9174418615
season12        -143281.2658139527
season13          33281.0509302334
season14         103265.5076744194
season15         143273.5444186057
season16         179779.0511627916
season17         312225.7179069777
season18         245839.3846511634
season19         162875.6413953498
season20         652951.7581395357
season21         425870.0848837215
season22         259596.6316279077
season23         206232.1083720934
season24         316585.4351162799
season25         220887.0918604656
season26         260269.0786046516
season27         164424.3453488378
season28         219162.4720930237
season29         195462.0188372096
season30         204473.8455813959
season31         177113.7523255819
season32          90318.7890697678
season33        -278827.3241860461
season34         264292.8225581399
season35          42682.7093023259
season36           8912.2860465119
season37          71726.5427906979
season38         206990.4695348841
season39         -47733.4337209300
season40          17143.0330232559
season41         -86539.1302325579
season42         -13619.8634883721
season43         -11515.5967441860
season44                        NA

código aplicado:

```
test <- window(dados_ts, start = 2020, drop.unused.levels = FALSE)
preditores <- tslm(test ~ trend + season)
fcast <- forecast(preditores)
autoplot(fcast) +
  ggtitle("Forecasts of beer production using regression") +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("megalitres")
```

Erro apresentado:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor season has new levels 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52
```

Comment: Oi Nívea, o erro que você ta buscando a solução é o de cima? Ou o de baixo?? Ficou um pouco confuso

Comment: o erro é o de baixo, o cod que apliquei foi o de cima